# Expandable Selector for column of raw

Tags: android, view

> I needed to create an app like Time Buddy exists in android playstore & iPhone app store.
>
> For that i needed to integrate tool which allow me to select all column of raw simultaneously and it also should be expandable. Prefer this screenshot for more understanding.

[image: Screenshot of Activty]

> Here this all all views are scrolling simultaneously, thats why i use scroll and add dynamically Linear Layout and then add dynamically view in it.
> Prefer My Code from Here.

## activity_test.xml#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llListTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

#TestActivity.java#

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
LinearLayout llListTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    llListTime = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llListTime);

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        LinearLayout llTimeView = new LinearLayout(TestActivity.this);
        llTimeView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                , LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        llTimeView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        llListTime.addView(llTimeView, j);

        for (int i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(TestActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.rv_time_raw, llTimeView, false);
            TextView txtRvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRvTime);
            if (i < 12) {
                txtRvTime.setText(i + " am");
            } else if (i == 12) {
                txtRvTime.setText(i + " pm");
            } else if (i > 12) {
                txtRvTime.setText((i - 12) + " pm");
            }
            llTimeView.addView(view, i - 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) llListTime.getChildAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
            View vw = ll.getChildAt(j);
            final int finalI = i;
            final int finalJ = j;
            vw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
                        LinearLayout pll = (LinearLayout) llListTime.getChildAt(p);
                        View pvw = pll.getChildAt(finalJ);
                        pvw.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
  }
}
```